# showdown.js extension: match multiword extension

Tags: javascript, regex, showdown

I want to create custom markdown tags using `showdown.js` such that:

```
==highlighted text==
```

renders:

```
<mark>highlighted text</mark>
```

Using the `twitter` extension as a baseline, I've been trying:

```
  // #highlighted# syntax
  {
    type:    'lang',
    regex:   '\\B(\\\\)?==([\\S]+)\\b',
    replace: function (match, leadingSlash, highlighted) {
      // Check if we matched the leading \ and return nothing changed if so
      if (leadingSlash === '\\') {
        return match;
      } else {
        return '<mark>' + highlighted + '</mark>';
      }
    }
  },
```

But this only lets me highlight single words, e.g.

- ==Apple ==Pear
- Apple Pear

I'd like to use `==` similar to `**`.

I assume the problem is the regex but can't seem to nail it. Can someone advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand question correctly you can use this simple regex:

```
regex: "==\\s*(.+?)\\s*==";
```

and use matched group #1.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gG8tM0/1)